# Automatically Sort Excel Columns When Data Changes - But With No Assumptions About My Data

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my situation:

- I have a spreadsheet in Excel 2010 setup with various columns.
- All of the columns are set to be filterable/sortable.
- There are filters set individually on some columns.
- There is a sort set via Data > Sort.
- The filters on the columns and the sorting are not fixed and will change.
- The data can be changed in any column

How can I make the spreadsheet automatically apply the filters and sorting whenever data is changed?

Any solution I can find online requires you to manually modify the VBA code to make it work with your specific data. You need to change things like: the range your data is in, the columns that need to be filtered by, the sorting that needs to be applied, etc, etc.

Some examples that I have found that don't live up to my expectations are [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/54295-auto-sort-list-values-excel.html), [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/14ef4712-550a-4615-a7a5-8795347a0091/excel-2007-column-auto-sorting), [and here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131222120630AAfyX9X)

Is there a script that I could drop into any Excel spreadsheet that meets my requirements?

Comment: It is possible, but would be alot of work. You will need to add code to the change event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx) and dynamically figure out the dimensions of your data and the current sort/filters applied to the data. Then clear the filters, resort, and re-apply the filters. I have not done what you are wanting myself, but it should definately be a do-able thing.  I would start with the macro recorder, and KB shortcuts for cell navigation.

Comment: @AlanWaage would it be possible to make this easily work if I have to specify only a range? Like column A-Z

Comment: @user1759942 thanks for the positive help. Just seeing if I was the first person in the world to have this problem

Answer (score 0):

I do not have possibility to check it now but adding any new criteria to existing filter and then removing it should re-filter the range.
Maybe the same would do with sorting.

 It could be triggered by worksheet_change() event.

This works when your filter is applied to ListObject:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.ListObject.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
End Sub
```

and does the thing with sorting as well.

Comment: What's a ListObject? My filter is applied to a column

Comment: I suppose it is called table (I do not use english version of Excel).  You can create this over existing data with ribbon Insert->Table (remember I translated this, it is a button next to pivot table)